# Is a volatile variable shared by all instances of an object?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have a java application implementing a game.

The class which is responsible for the game as a whole also implements the Runnable interface, and overrides the run method, implementing the process of playing the game. This run() method contains a loop that will continue to run until a `private volatile boolean endThread` is set to true. This would be done through a method called stop() where endThread is set to true.

I want to be able to stop a particular thread from my main method, calling stop() to end a particular thread playing the game, ending the thread.

```
public class Game implements Runnable{
  private volatile boolean endThread;

  public Game(){
    endThread = false;
  }

  public void run(){
    while(endThread != true){
      // insert code to simulate the process of running the game
    }
    System.out.println("Game ended. Ending thread.");
  }

  public void stop(){ 
    endThread = true;
  }
}

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Game gameOne = new Game();
    Thread threadOne = new Thread(gameOne);
    threadOne.start();
    Game gameTwo = new Game();
    Thread threadTwo = new Thread(gameTwo);
    threadTwo.start();
    threadTwo.stop(); // will this stop threadOne aswell?
  }
}
```

What I'm wondering is if the variable is volatile will each instance of the game class share the same endThread variable, so that when one thread is stopped using stop(), all other threads stop too?

Comment: no - volatile means only that write and read from variable marked as `volatile` is atomic, not less, not more

Comment: “… the volatile modifier guarantees that any thread that reads a field will see the most recently written value.” - Josh Bloch . So, no not shared.

Comment: @bag you are confusing visibility (which volatile gives) with sharedness (which static gives). If you want all threads to see the up-to-date value of the variable, it needs to be volatile.

Comment: @AndyTurner by "all threads see the up-to-date value of the variable", do you mean that each thread will see the true up-to-date value, as set from the main method, of the variable in that particular threads game class? Or is it that all threads can see the value of the same variable?

Comment: @bag each Thread will have it's *own* instance (it does not have the static modifier). So when you call `stop`, only that particular Thread will see the value as being `true`.

Comment: Since you haven't deigned to share any code for how you start your threads, we can't be sure of much. I will say that extending `Thread` is a ghastly approach.

Comment: @Eugene, if what you said were true, how could one ever share data between threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need the volatile modifier here, since it introduces visibility. If you remove the `volatile` you *might never see the updated value* while reading, the volatile keyword will ensure that once written, other threads can see it.

What you are confusing is `static` here which is a *per-class* as opposed to *per-instance*.

There is a must-read article [here](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.md/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html)

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Each instance of the game class will have its own endThread, but the volatile modifier will allow the variable to be written to and changed from main(), so that it will be truly checked from main memory in the termination condition of the loop in run(), and end that particular thread. Is this correct?

Comment: @bag yes, it's not *really* from main-memory, but you can think it like that (it is a cache coherence protocol that does the `sync` so that all threads see a consistent view of the world).

Comment: No, @bag, that isn't exactly correct. Each thread shares the `endThread` variable but has its own view of it. If the variable were not shared, data could not be transferred between threads. So when thread `A` modifies `endThread`, other threads do potentially see the change, and will certainly see the change if proper synchronization is used.

Comment: @LewBloch so if I was to change the variable in thread A from the main method in order to stop thread A, would that also stop thread B, C, D and so on, since they're all instances of the same class?

Comment: If the threads are started from the same instance of a class `Foo`, which you haven't shown us, they will share all the instance variables of that `Foo` object. All threads are run in instances of `Thread`, but I'm ​not sure it's correct to say that a thread is an instance of any class. Certainly it is not correct that a thread is an instance of `Foo`, the type of the instance from which it was created.

Comment: @LewBloch Ah yes, I think I meant to say that they're all ran from instances of the same class. Every time I want to create a new game, I will create a new instance of the class Game, which would extend Thread and implement the run() method. Then I would start that thread. So in this case, each thread would have its own instance - so each thread will have its own endThread, right?

Comment: Show the code. How can we know what's going on, otherwise?

Comment: @LewBloch Code example added.

Comment: Okay, in this style of invocation the `endThread` variables are separate, because you are starting each thread with a different instance of `Game`. So the threads do not share `endThread` and will not see each other's changes to that variable. In fact, there's no need for it to be `volatile` because it is not shared data.

Comment: @bag LewBloch is absolutely right. Each Thread has it's own instance that is *not shared* among them. Since there is no sharing of the `endThread` variable whatsoever, there is no need to make it `volatile`.